# Quicktime Player recording with Applescript broken on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, applescript, quicktime

I have this simple code:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
activate
new screen recording
document "Screen Recording" start
delay 10
document "Screen Recording" stop
end tell
```

This records a 10-second movie on my 10.8 machine with no problem. 
But on 10.9 mac-mini, QT hangs at the stop action above. 
It hangs at the window with message "Finishing Recording". 
I have to force quit it and still same thing. If I do these steps manually, they work. But with AppleScript or even same steps with Automator have same issue.

I upgraded to 10.9.2, but still same issue.

Is this a known bug? Any suggestions for a work around?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: I checked your script for myself and find the same hanging issue on 10.9. So your question is valid. Unfortunately I don't have a solution.

Comment: Thanks regulus6633 for checking on your end. It seems to be a really weird bug.

Answer (score 3):

I do something like this to record the screen from CI and it always works for me:

```html
set filePath to (path to desktop as string) & "ScreenRecordingFile.mov"

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Simulator"
 set frontmost to true
end tell

tell application "QuickTime Player"
 activate
 set newScreenRecording to new screen recording
 delay 1
 tell application "System Events"
  tell process "QuickTime Player"
   set frontmost to true
   key code 49
  end tell
 end tell
 tell newScreenRecording
  start
  delay 15
  stop
 end tell
 export document 1 in (file filePath) using settings preset "720p"
 close document 1 saving no
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into the same problem and found out, that the problem is not in the `stop`, but in the non-interactive `start`, so I've tried to start recording (pseudo)interactively and it worked out perfectly.

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
    activate
    new screen recording
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player"
        key code 49
    end tell
    document "Screen Recording" start
    delay 10
    document "Screen Recording" stop
end tell
```

It still calls `start` instead of emulating click, because I haven't found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Two tricks are needed:

1. Send a space key to the QuickTime Player before start to avoid the `Finishing...` dialog being stuck.  (credits to @outring)
2. We need to simulate a mouse click. This is not easy, and we need to do it via CoreGraphics (aka Quartz). We can either write in Objective-C (need compilation), in Python (via PyObjc bridge) or Swift.
3. Somehow recording starts roughly 2 seconds after the mouse click, so we need to sleep 12 seconds for a 10-second video.

A working script will look like this:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
   activate
   new screen recording
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "QuickTime Player" to key code 49
   document "Screen Recording" start
   do shell script "python -c 'import Quartz; mouse_location = Quartz.NSEvent.mouseLocation(); [ Quartz.CGEventPost(Quartz.kCGHIDEventTap, Quartz.CGEventCreateMouseEvent(None, mouse_action, mouse_location, Quartz.kCGMouseButtonLeft)) for mouse_action in [ Quartz.kCGEventLeftMouseDown, Quartz.kCGEventLeftMouseUp ] ]'"
   delay 12
   document "Screen Recording" stop
end tell
```